# RegisterType with parameter in Unity DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

## Problem

I have one interface IFoo and there are diffrent class implemented this interface like Foo1, Foo2, Foo3 and so on. now I have a service IBarService which is implemented  by BarService and it takes a parameter Foo1 in its constructor.

```
public class BarService : IBarService
{
    private readonly Foo1 _foo1;
    public BarService (Foo1 foo1)
    {
        this._foo1 = foo1; // foo1 this parameter value is not loaded 
    }

    public virtual string SomeFunction()
    { 
      var value =_foo1.x; //This value is empty
    }
}
```

now my problem is how I can register it.right now I am doing this.

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo , Foo1>();
container.RegisterType<IBarService, BarService >();
```

this code instantiate foo1 with empty value during rigistration I am updateing Foo1 properties but it is not injecting in BarService. How can I achieve this?

### Update

In addition my IFoo interface is following

```
public interface IFoo
{
}
```

and it is implemented by other class like

```
public class Foo1: IFoo
{
    public bool X{ get; set; }
    public string Y{ get; set; }
    public List<string> Z{ get; set; }
}
```

while registering the class in unityconfig I am loading all the Foo1 values from database and set it. at this point every this is working fine but now I want the Foo1 class to inject with the loaded values in  the BarService .

I want to inject constructor parameter into the BarService with preloaded values ho can I do this

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please revise the last paragraph.

Comment: I am trying to use already instantiated object of Foo1 and pass it into the BarService

Comment: Please show that in the question

Comment: for example foo1 object which is passed in barService has some properties like x,y,z. but the values of x,y,z is null

Comment: Is information that Foo1 and Foo2 implement IFoo interface relevant?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your constructor for `BarService` shouldn't take a `Foo1`, but instead it should take an `IFoo`, otherwise Unity will not consider any parameters you'd have set in the `container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo1>();` registration, if any (aka: That line becomes useless.)

Right now, when you do `container.Resolve<IBarService>()`, what Unity does is :

1. "He wants an `IBarService`. What do I have? Oh, I should instantiate a `BarService`!
2. How should I instantiate `BarService`? I guess I'll just use the constructor I see, but I need a `Foo1`.
3. Do I have a recipe for `Foo1`? No? Alright, I'll use the public constructor I have for that. **Since it's the default constructor, it doesn't set any properties.**

I see two solutions to your problem :

**1) Register Foo with another lifetime manager, and modify the object.**

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

If you register foo in that fashion, once it's resolved, it will always return the same instance. You could then modify it, and the change would persist.

**2) Register Foo with construction overrides.**

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(
    new InjectionProperty("X", valueOfX),
    new InjectionProperty("Y", valueOfY),
    new InjectionProperty("Z", valuesOfZ));
```

With that, once Foo is instanciated, the public properties named "X", "Y", "Z" will be set.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't register type Foo1 in your container.

```
 myContainer.RegisterType<Foo1>();
```

More info:
Default lifetime (lifestyle) of Unity registered objects is *transient*. It means Unity will create *new* object of Foo1 on every call.
You should check out singleton lifetime. Here is code from MSDN:

```
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyObject, MySingletonObject>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: Simply registering a type like that doesn't do anything. To get any kind of utility you'd need either, register a specific type to a basetype, change the lifetime controller or have resolution overrides.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @Tipx,

```
public BarService (Foo1 foo1)
```

should be changed to

```
public BarService (IFoo foo1)
```

to use any form of dependency injection. Until then the container registration does not make any difference.

Or did you mean to have Foo1 as the parameter in this way:

```
private readonly IFoo _foo;
public BarService (Foo1 foo1)
{
    this._foo = foo1;
}
```

This is valid as well in which case container registration is still not needed for IFoo.

If you really intended to do dependency injection, here is how it should be done.

```
public class BarService : IBarService
{
    private readonly IFoo _foo;

    public BarService(IFoo foo)
    {
        this._foo = foo;
    }
}
```

and in the container registration, you can keep changing the resolving type to any concrete class Foo1, Foo2 or Foo3.

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo , Foo1>();
```

or

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo , Foo2>();
```

If still empty value is coming, after following the suitable approach, please post more of your code which would help us in understanding why it is null. I tried the above piece of code and proper values are coming.